# Get model attributes without making them required for modelform_factory?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I've got a modelform_factory which works perfect for what I need.

I call it like this:

```
    dep_formset = modelformset_factory(
        Dependent,
        fields=('has_medical', 'med_group_id'),
        max_num = dep_count
    )
```

As you might guess, Dependent has additional fields that I want to use simply for display purposes (`first_name` and `last_name` respectively)  I want to show the first_name and last_name of the dependent person - but have it be simply for display, not edit.

If I add 'first_name' and 'last_name' to the fields in the above, I can then access them in my template - but the form fails against `.is_valid()` because I'm displaying them simply as text and not as an input, so they're not being POST'ed

Is there some clever way to get access to the first_name and last_name of the dependent objects without adding them to fields for the formset_factory?

The template looks like this (partial snippet so you can see what I'm trying to do with the first_name, last_name):

```
{% for form in dep_formset %}
    {{ form.id }}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="g">
        <h4>{{ form.first_name.value }} {{form.last_name.value}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="g dependent-option">
        <div class="g-1-4 dependent-option-check">
            {% if form.has_medical %}
```

Comment: So the formset is tied to an already created instance of `Dependent`? If yes then you can access the associated instance in template `{{ form.instance.first_name }}`

Comment: That worked a treat! please post as the answer so I can mark it! :)

Comment: Glad it helped, posted as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided information it looks like the `formset` is tied to an instance which you can access in template:

```
{{ form.instance.first_name }}
```